# Kubuntu 20.04, Wireguard and systemd-resolved DNS leak

Tags: ubuntu, dns, systemd, wireguard, resolv.conf

Fresh install of Kubuntu 20.04 (uses systemd-resolve by default) with Wireguard installed. I have a wg tunnel (going through a wifi interface *wlp0s20f3*) and all traffic is supposed to route through that tunnel and almost all of it does. However, DNS requests are routed through the wifi interface (*wlp0s20f3*) for some reason. Here is the wg configuration (*wg0*)

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.7/32
PrivateKey = [[PRIVATE KEY]]
DNS = 213.136.95.10,213.136.95.11

[Peer]
PublicKey = [[PUBLIC KEY]]
PresharedKey = [[PRESHARED KEY]]
Endpoint = [[IP:PORT]]
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

`/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` which looks as expected

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search dlinkrouter
```

As soon as I establish the wg tunnel (*wg0*) I peek into `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` and see

```
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 213.136.95.10
nameserver 213.136.95.11
search dlinkrouter
```

The DNS of the Wifi network stays on top even though the *wg0* DNS servers are added below it.

I run the following to make sure

```
$ resolvectl dns
Global: 213.136.95.10 213.136.95.11
Link 17 (wg0): 213.136.95.10 213.136.95.11
Link 2 (wlp0s20f3): 192.168.0.1
```

```
$ resolvectl domain
Global:
Link 17 (wg0): ~.
Link 2 (wlp0s20f3): ~. dlinkrouter
```

```
$ resolvectl query google.com
google.com: 172.217.17.238                     -- link: wlp0s20f3

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 8.5ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
```

https://www.dnsleaktest.com/ also reports the DNS leak.

There is nothing configured in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`.

A temporary work-around is to go to the NetworkManager and edit the network setting of the WiFi connection where I set IPv4 -> Method -> Automatic (only addresses) which does not take the DNS address from DHCP but I'd have to do that for every network I ever connect to which doesn't sound like a very good idea.

Any ideas on how to fix this are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> $ resolvectl domain
> Global:
> Link 17 (wg0): ~.
> Link 2 (wlp0s20f3): ~. dlinkrouter
> ```

It's a problem in old versions of NetworkManager. This shows that *all* of your interfaces have `~.` unnecessarily specified; this makes them equal priority and systemd-resolved will send requests over both. [See this blog post.](https://blogs.gnome.org/mcatanzaro/2020/12/17/understanding-systemd-resolved-split-dns-and-vpn-configuration/)

In general `~.` shouldn't be set on any interface except for a privacy VPN such as your wg0.

You can probably work around this by setting `systemd-resolved=false` in NetworkManager.conf (so that the only settings there come from other tools such as wg-quick, not from NM) or by completely replacing /etc/resolv.conf with a file that is not managed by systemd-resolved and just has your static DNS server listed.

> I peek into /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf and see [...] The DNS of the Wifi network stays on top even though the wg0 DNS servers are added below it.

That's mostly irrelevant. Nothing on your system uses this file and it doesn't represent the way systemd-resolved performs DNS lookups.

Comment: Thank you. I also needed to add dns=no for it to work. Still, I'd say that is a pretty severe security issue, if you want privacy and think that your wg tunnel keeps you protected. By default in the latest Kubuntu LTS that is obviously not the case.